# Msg 102, Level 15, Line 1 , Incorrect syntax (however ...)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and I've got the following query to import the records from my csv. 
However it keeps giving me this syntax error

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\update_05112013.csv' INTO TABLE dbo.Urls
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Perhaps I'm missing something small , probably ??
Can any of you guys see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think you are trying to use a mysql specific command in Sql Server. You need to use Bulk Insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server `BULK INSERT` is a good way to insert data in bulk (as the name suggests) but it doesn't actually support CSV files:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188609.aspx

> Comma-separated value (CSV) files are not supported by SQL Server
>   bulk-import operations. However, in some cases, a CSV file can be used
>   as the data file for a bulk import of data into SQL Server.

If you can create a CSV without quotation marks or escaped characters this will work:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Urls FROM 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\update_05112013.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```